# Simple Pong game in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a simple pong game in Java for Processing. I have not finished yet and everything has been going well except I can't make the ball bounce off the pong paddles. I have successfully made it so that if the ball goes below the paddle it bounces back, but for some reason, the ball will go through if its above the paddle.

This is my current code, my current problem is in the paddleFunctions tab in the `void animatePaddles` function:

main tab:

```
Ball ball;
Paddle primary, secondary;

void setup()
{
  size(1000, 500);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  frameRate(150);
  ball = new Ball();
  initializePaddles();  // enters x values into primary and secondary paddles
}
void draw()
{
  ball.animateBall();  //uses vectors to add movements to ball, also checks if hitting walls
  animatePaddles();  //adds movements to paddles
}
```

Ball class:

```
class Ball
{
  PVector location, direction;
  final int diameter = height/20;
  Ball()
  {
    location = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    direction = new PVector(0.5, 0.5);
  }
  void animateBall()  //movement to balls and checking if hitting walls
  {
    background(0);
    fill(255);
    circle(location.x, location.y, diameter);
    location.add(direction);
    if (location.y+diameter/2>= height|| location.y<=diameter/2)
      direction.y*=-1;
  }
}
```

Paddle class:

```
class Paddle  //class for paddles
{
  PVector location;
  PVector direction = new PVector(0, 0);
  final int paddleLength = height/5;
  final int paddleWidth = width/150;
}
```

paddleFunctions tab:

```
void initializePaddles()  //enters x values into paddles relative screen size
{
  primary = new Paddle();
  primary.location= new PVector(width*.987, height/2);
  secondary = new Paddle();
  secondary.location = new PVector(width*.007, height/2);
}

void animatePaddles()  //creates the paddles and adds movement
{
  fill(255);
  rect(primary.location.x, primary.location.y, primary.paddleWidth, primary.paddleLength);
  rect(secondary.location.x, secondary.location.y, secondary.paddleWidth, secondary.paddleLength);
  primary.location.add(primary.direction);
  secondary.location.add(secondary.direction);
  if (ball.location.x+ball.diameter/2==primary.location.x-primary.paddleWidth/2 && ball.location.y>=primary.location.y-primary.paddleLength/2 && ball.location.y<=primary.location.y+primary.paddleLength/2)  //THE PROBLEM
    ball.direction.x*=-1;  //^^ **PROBLEM**
}

void keyPressed()  //controls primary paddle
{
  if (key == CODED)
    if (keyCode == UP)
      primary.direction.y=-2;
    else if (keyCode == DOWN)
      primary.direction.y=2;
}

void keyReleased()
{
  primary.direction.y=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion is wrong. The coordinate  which is passed to [`rect()`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) is not the center of the rectangle, by default it is the top left corner. But you can change the mode by [`rectMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html):

```java
rectMode(CENTER);
rect(primary.location.x, primary.location.y, primary.paddleWidth, primary.paddleLength);
rect(secondary.location.x, secondary.location.y, secondary.paddleWidth, secondary.paddleLength);
```

Since you operate with floating point numbers, the ball will never hit the paddle exactly. You've to evaluate if the right of the ball is greater than the left of the paddle:

```java
if (ball.location.x+ball.diameter/2 >= primary.location.x-+primary.paddleWidth/2 && 
    ball.location.y >= primary.location.y-primary.paddleLength/2 &&
    ball.location.y <= primary.location.y+primary.paddleLength/2) {

    ball.direction.x *= -1;
}
```